# Visual Studio 2010 - it takes FOREVER to start web application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, delay

If I open my web app, then build it and run it (with or without debugger) Visual will be unresponsive for next ~ 30 minutes. After that the app will start and I can build, rebuild and run the same application, normally (no delay anymore).

I don't know what is going on - I thought it was a problem with `WebDev.WebServer40.EXE`...
But if I run the server manually from `cmd` (after building my app), it will start-up without delay...

The computer I'm on, has `Windows 7 Pro` (x64 edition), a lot of software is installed (computer have been running without re-installation for more then a year now), but the slow app start-up problem appeared recently (about 2 months ago it happened first time).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed any Service Packs for VS2010?

Comment: Yes SP1 is installed, exact VS version is: "10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel"

Answer (score 1):

Remove your site from `Temporary ASP.Net Files`

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\siteName
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped a bit (now it takes about 1 instead of 30 minutes to get out of "hanged" state) I will test some more tomorrow, and mark this as answer if nothing will change.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - unfortunately, it didn't help. I also tried deleting

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

but it didn't help either. Any other ideas?